# What's the significance of Wil Wheaton wearing a Star Trek uniform when visiting the cinema for the Star Wars movie?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

Was there any significance to Wil Wheaton being in the theater to watch Star Wars with Koothrapali, Leonard, and Howard, while wearing a Star Fleet uniform in **The Big Bang Theory** episode ***["The Opening Night Excitation"](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/The_Opening_Night_Excitation)***?

[image]

Comment: Depends if you know who Wil Wheaton actually is, I guess.

Comment: I tried to improve the title by reducing the supposed ambiguity while avoiding a reference to an uspecified episode.

Comment: @cde: Thanks, my edit probably wasn't great. I like Napoleons though, seems a touch more concise.

Answer (score 35):

The plot and dialog from the episode answer this. Wil Wheaton is a troll, and enjoys messing with people (remember the bowling games?). And he's most known for playing Wesley on Star Trek TNG. The Trekkie vs Jedi (Star Trek vs Star Wars fans) feud is as famous as the [Hatfields and McCoys (No, not *that* McCoy.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatfield%E2%80%93McCoy_feud)

[From wikia:](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/The_Opening_Night_Excitation)

> At the movies, the audience starts booing since Wil Wheaton shows up in a Star Trek uniform dressed as Mr. Spock. Wil is loving the rejection. **He tells the guys that since he was on Star Trek he's rooting for the home team.** Someone calls out that Star Trek stinks. Wil replies, **"Live long and suck it."**

From the transcript:

> Oh, did you hear from Wil?
>   Yeah, he's on his way. Time for bladder check.
>   Check.
>   Check.
>   Check. Wait. Screw it. I'm holding it.
>   (crowd booing)
>   What is everyone booing at?
>   (booing continues)
>   **Wheaton**: Hey, guys. What's up?
>   Um, hey, Wil.  What you doing?
>   **Wheaton**: **I was on Star Trek. I'm just rooting for the home team.**
>   Man: Star Trek stinks!
>   **Wheaton**: Yeah? Live long and suck it!

Someone should have told him to "Shut Up, Wesley", that really pisses him off (in real life):

[image: Tweet (and reply): (Wil) "NEW RULE: I'm officially over people saying "Shut up, Wesley" to me, even in jest. From now on, I'm insta-blocking anyone who does that." (Patrick Stewart) "@wilw Shut up Wil."]

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that **Star Trek** takes place in the **Milky Way** whilst the **Star Wars** take place in a galaxy **far away** (depending on your point of view) - hence the **Home Team** comment.

Comment: The Hatfields and McCoys are almost completely unknown outside of the States (I'd never heard of them before reading your answer), while the Star Trek / Star Wars rivalry is moderately known amongst those people who know that they're different franchises.

Comment: Should have been **Live long and smell it** :D

Answer (score 9):

Wil Wheaton played [Wesley Crusher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wesley_Crusher) on Star Trek: The Next Generation.

It's a simple joke that despite seeing Star Wars, he's wearing his Star Trek uniform instead.

Comment: It's simple-ish but it does rely on an understanding that there's a rivalry between the two fandoms.